# Divide String in Swift by Brackets

Tags: macos, swift

I'm getting the following data as a String. Now I would like to parse that string.

```
{{"1", "test.pdf", 495207}, {"2", "test2.ics", 972}}`
```

I would like to divide the String first into

```
{"1", "test.pdf", 495207}
{"2", "test2.ics", 972}
```

An then i would have a class that i would instanciate like this

```
test(1, "test.pdf", 495207)
test(2, "test2.ics", 972)
```

How can I do this with Swift? Is Split a possible solution. If i choose `,` It would split to many times.

**UPDATE**

I was not precise enough. My result should not be the String of each bracket. I would like to access the values `1`,`test.pdf` etc and save put them into a variable for further processing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you replace in source string braces "`{}`" with square braces "`[]`" the source become a valid Json - array with 2 elements, each element is an array with 3 values - than you can parse it using `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
var source = "{{\"1\", \"test.pdf\", 495207}, {\"2\", \"test2.ics\", 972}}"
var string = source.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("{", withString: "[")
string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("}", withString: "]")

let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
let json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.allZeros, error: nil) as? [AnyObject]

var objects: [MyClass] = []

if let array = json {
    for element in array {
        let array    = element as! [AnyObject]
        let id       = array[0] as! String
        let filename = array[1] as! String
        let number   = array[2] as! UInt
        objects.append(MyClass(id: id, filename: filename, number: number))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution can be-

```
    var str = "{{\"1\", \"EX9OEH.pdf\", 495207}, {\"2\", \"BAHN_Fahrplan_20150814.ics\", 972}}"

    struct Item
    {
      var first : String
      var second : String
      var third : String
    }


    //First get the contents as a string by stripping opening and closing braces
    //Range-
    let range  = Range(start: (advance(str.startIndex, 1)),
      end: advance(str.endIndex, -1))

    //Strip all quotes

    str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\"", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    //Strip all braces
    str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("{", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)
    str = str.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("}", withString: "", options: NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch, range: nil)


    //Get the components seperated by comma

    var components = str.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: ","))

 //Build the item objects-
    var items:[Item]  = []

    var i:Int = 0

    while (i < components.count){
      //Extract 3 components per item
       var item = Item(first: components[ i ], second: components[ i + 1], third: components[i + 2])
      i += 3
      items.append(item)

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to replace the chars in the correct order:

```
text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("{{", withString: "{")

    text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("}}", withString: "}")

    text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("{", withString: "(")

    text.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("}", withString: ")")
```